# JavaScript, elegant way to check nested object properties for null/undefined

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

a "problem" which i have every now and then is that i have an object e.g. `user = {}` and through the course of using the app this gets populated. Let's say somwhere, after an AJAX call or something i do this:

```
user.loc = {
    lat: 50,
    long: 9
}
```

At another place i want to check if `user.loc.lat` exists.

```
if (user.loc.lat) {
    // do something
}
```

If it does not exists, this will cause an error. If `user.loc.lat` is `undefined`, `user.loc` of course is `undefined` as well.

```
"Cannot read property 'lat' of null" - Dev Tools error
```

That means I need to check it like this:

```
if (user.loc) {
    if (user.loc.lat) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

or

```
if (user.loc && user.loc.lat) {
    // do something
}
```

This isn't really pretty and the bigger my objects are the worse it gets - obviously (imagine 10 levels of nesting).
It kind bums me that `if(user.loc.lat)` isn't just returning `false` if `user.loc` is `undefined` as well.

What's the ideal way to check situations like this?

Comment: Try this `if(user && user.loc && user.loc.lat) {`

Comment: You can check value of null and undefined using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @AamirAfridi—even though that's how the OP was written, the test should stop at the last object, not the property. e.g. the test will return false if `user.loc.lat` exists but has a falsey value (such as `0`).  :-)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can use an utility function like this:

```
get = function(obj, key) {
    return key.split(".").reduce(function(o, x) {
        return (typeof o == "undefined" || o === null) ? o : o[x];
    }, obj);
}
```

Usage:

```
 get(user, 'loc.lat')     // 50
 get(user, 'loc.foo.bar') // undefined
```

Or, to check only if a property exists, without getting its value:

```
has = function(obj, key) {
    return key.split(".").every(function(x) {
        if(typeof obj != "object" || obj === null || ! x in obj)
            return false;
        obj = obj[x];
        return true;
    });
}

if(has(user, 'loc.lat')) ...
```

Comment: The problem with the *get* approach is that it may return a property from anywhere in the chain, it doesn't specifically test for the last property.

Comment: @RobG How so?  As soon as it hits an undefined that just gets passed all the way through and the result is undefined.

Comment: @RobG: Updated `has` for more accurate type checking, so that `has('foo.bar.baz')` won't fail if `foo.bar` is, say, a number.

Comment: @JamesMontagne—`get({foo:{bar:{fum:undefined}}},'foo.fog')` returns *undefined* because *fog* isn't a property of *bar*, not because it read the value. Similarly , *has* should check for the existence of the property, not whether attempting to read the value returns *undefined* or *null*. It will also fail if *obj* is a function object or a host object where *typeof* doesn't return *object* (it isn't required to and doesn't in some browsers).

Comment: @RobG  _"`get({foo:{bar:{fum:undefined}}},'foo.fog')` returns undefined because fog isn't a property of bar, not because it read the value."_ ....well since there is no value to read, that property will be undefined...that's the point.

Comment: Your answer says "*to check only if a property exists*", but it doesn't, it checks the returned value, which is quite different. Also, due to operator precedence, `! x in obj` is evaluated as `(!x) in obj` so it's checking for a property name of "true" or "false", depending on the result of `!x` (which will always be *true* since it's a string), so the result of that expression will be *false* unless there is a property `obj.true`. I think you mean it to be `!(x in obj)`.

Comment: I wish lodash would and a function for this.`_.has` is the closest but doesn't check the value.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, it does! Just use `_.get` http://stackoverflow.com/a/24046380/654708

Comment: This code has flaw it's not full prof    
    

    right code is 

    has = function(obj, key) {
    return key.split(".").every(function(x) {
        if(typeof obj != "object" || obj === null || !( x in obj))
            return false;
        obj = obj[x];
        return true;
    });

Comment: This article truly summarizes all the ways of doing this : https://hackernoon.com/accessing-nested-objects-in-javascript-f02f1bd6387f

Comment: How to default this to 0 if it's `undefined`?

Comment: It doesn't work for me unless I write `! x in obj` as `! (x in obj)`.

Comment: it does not work for array item, like  `a.b[0]`

Answer (score 32):

You can combine the checks using lazy `and`:

```
if(user.loc && user.loc.lat) { ...
```

Or, you use CoffeeScript. And ES2020 has new syntax ( Nullish coalescing Operator ).

```
user.loc?.lat?. '...'
```

which would run the checks for `loc` property and safeguard against empty objects.

Comment: sorry, you were all very fast in answering. Your first approach is also a case that i want to avoid. Consider that i have huge object with 5 to 15 levels of nesting.

Comment: You don't have a lot of options here.  (1) property checking, manually, or with CoffeeScript, (2) try/catch.  If you have an object with 15 levels of nesting and its property may be absent at any level, then I'd think you have some sub-optimal design patterns with you application.

Comment: It's an example. I want a way to cover that scenario. I obviously would avoid 15 levels of nesting but what if an old server-side application just does it that way and i have to deal with it? That's why i wanted to cover that scenario

Comment: `.?` is called the `optional chaining operator`. The nullish coalescing operator` (`??`) is very different and more similar to the OR operator (`||`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#relationship_with_the_optional_chaining_operator_.

Answer (score 28):

Well, javascript has try-catch. Depending on what you actually need to do (i.e. what your `else` statement would look like if it's `undefined`), that may be what you want.

example:

```
try {
   user.loc.lat.doSomething();
} catch(error) {
   //report
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to throw exceptions instead of if-else, if you know that a var may be unset, I don't consider that an exception, thus you should handle it without throwing in a try-catch. (Of course you might throw in the else-clause) then.

Comment: I like this solution for simple stuff that sometimes get harder to read with conditionals.
@JonasStensved is pointing no using try catch on this because launching exception (you are not launching it until you write `throw`, i think) but the problem could be something else goes wrong in the block and you will not be able to detect it on the future.

Comment: @pikilon Rule of thumb: Do not use exceptions for flow control. In your case something really is unexpected and an exception, then throw. Otherwise handle it as any other code condition.

Answer (score 8):

Try this `if(user && user.loc && user.loc.lat) {...}`

You can check value of null and undefined using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

If `.loc` has value `false` than you can try

`if(user && user.loc && typeof(user.loc)!=="undefined"){...}`

If you have a huge nested object than have a look at

[**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key).

```
function checkNested(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
      obj = args.shift();

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    obj = obj[args[i]];
  }
  return true;
}

var test = {level1:{level2:{level3:'level3'}} };

checkNested(test, 'level1', 'level2', 'level3'); // true
checkNested(test, 'level1', 'level2', 'foo'); // false
```

**Update:**
Try [lodash.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.0#get)

Comment: sorry, you were all very fast in answering. This is also a case that i want to avoid. Consider that i have huge object with 5 to 15 levels of nesting.

Comment: I hate people down voting without adding a comment.