# Accessing nested arrays/properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The utility function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23809123/3967289) allows to easily access nested properties of objects and returns null (or undefined) if one of the parent properties does not exist.

**original Code:**

> ```
> get = function(obj, key) {
>     return key.split(".").reduce(function(o, x) {
>         return (typeof o == "undefined" || o === null) ? o : o[x];
>     }, obj);
> }
>  get(user, 'loc.lat')     // 50
>  get(user, 'loc.foo.bar') // undefined
> ```

I really want to use this, but i need to be able to work with nested arrays as well.

**Examples:**

```
var childArray = [0,1,2]
var parentArray = [{myArray: childArray}]
var obj = {key: parentArray}
```

I want to extend the utility function like this:

```
get(obj, 'key[0].myArray[2]');      // 2
get(obj, 'key[0].foo[2]');          // null
get(obj, 'key[0].myArray[42]');     // null
```

And ideally it should also be able to evaluate this as well

```
var childArray = [0,1,2]
var parentArray = [childArray, childArray]
var obj = {key: parentArray}

get(obj, 'key[1][0]');     // 0
get(obj, 'foo[1][0]');     // null
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to access an array `arr` with a given string-reference like `"arr[0]"` (without regex to remove the brackets...)?

Do you know a more elegant solution that achieves the result presented in the examples above?

Comment: Just change the "path": `get(obj, 'key.0.myArray.2')` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1twrxeor/))

Comment: Please make this an answer, i will upvote and possibly accept this as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to change the path/key you're passing to `get()`

From

```
get(obj, 'key[0].myArray[2]');
```

To

```
get(obj, 'key.0.myArray.2');
```

```js
var get = function(obj, key) {
    return key.split(".").reduce(function(o, x) {
        return (typeof o == "undefined" || o === null) ? o : o[x];
    }, obj);
}

var childArray = [0,1,2]
var parentArray = [{myArray: childArray}]
var obj = {key: parentArray}

console.log(get(obj, 'key.0.myArray.2'));      // 2
console.log(get(obj, 'key.0.foo.2'));          // null
console.log(get(obj, 'key.0.myArray.42'));     // null

var childArray2 = [0,1,2]
var parentArray2 = [childArray2, childArray2]
var obj2 = {key: parentArray2}

console.log(get(obj2, 'key.1.0'));     // 0
console.log(get(obj2, 'foo.1.0'));     // null
```

Answer (score 1):

With an invention of `Object.prototype.getNestedValue()` you can dynamically access deeply nested values through object properties and array indices. All you have to do is to provide the nested properties and indices dynamically as arguments in the correct order.

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

var arr = [{fox: [{turn:[857, 432]}]}, {sax: [{pana:[777, 987]}]}, {ton: [{joni:[123, 567]}]}, {piu: [{burn:[666, 37]}]}, {sia: [{foxy:[404, 696]}]}],
  myObj = { foo : 1, bar: { baz : 2 }, bee : 3 },
   arg1 = 3,
   arg2 = "piu",
   arg3 = 0,
   arg4 = "burn",
   arg5 = 1;

document.write(arr.getNestedValue(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would instead use an array of property names, which would allow you easy recursion.

But if you want to go back to your original pattern, you could still transform your expression into this array.

Have a look on this example:

```js
var innerget = function(object, proparr) {
  if(proparr.length == 0) 
    return object;
  
  if(typeof object == "undefined" || object === null)
    return object;
  return innerget(object[proparr.splice(0, 1)], proparr);
};

var get = function(object, expr) {
  var proparr = expr.replace(/\[/g, ".").replace(/\]/g, "").split(".");
  return innerget(object, proparr);
}

var object = {
   key: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]  
};

document.write(innerget(object, ['key', 'key2', 2]) + "<br>");
document.write(innerget(object, ['key', 0, 2]) + "<br>");
document.write(get(object, "key[0][1]"));
```