# How can i check if an object is undefined (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, undefined, javascript-objects

I have to check if a object is undefined but when i do

```
typeof myUnexistingObject.myUnexistingValue == 'undefined'
```

i get this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myUnexistingObject is not defined
```

so, how can I check for undefined obects or properties?

Comment: Since the object is undefined, you first need to check if the object is defined before checking the value

Comment: Hmm i tried to check the undefined object, if it is not undefined i have to check if it has some undefined values but i got an error, " Cannot read property 'original' of undefined".

Comment: @Manu: don't access the property if the variable is empty or doesn't exist.

Comment: For more elegant way of **checking nested object properties**, you can use a method presented by @georg in **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23809123/1977012)** or see this mature post **[JavaScript test for existence of nested object key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/1977012)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check for each potentially defined property before using it:

```js
function checkUnexistingObject(myUnexistingObject) {
  if (myUnexistingObject !== undefined) {
    if (myUnexistingObject.otherObject !== undefined) {
      console.log("All is well");
    }
  }
}
checkUnexistingObject({});
checkUnexistingObject({otherObject: "hey"});
```

Comment: That will still throw an error in the OP's case, since `myUnexisistingObject` isn't even declared.

Comment: I don't think op said that myUnexistingObject wasn't declared.

Comment: But the error they are getting says that.

Comment: Okay, I know what you mean, but declared !== defined.

Comment: Sure. I'm just saying that the OP would get exactly the same error with your solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're right, my bad.