# Javascript safely check for nested children

Tags: javascript

My question is pretty much the same as [JavaScript, elegant way to check nested object properties for NULL/undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808928/javascript-elegant-way-to-check-nested-object-properties-for-null-undefined)

however instead of dot notation in dictionaries I need to be able to do the same with dom for example:

`div[0].children[1].children[0].children[1]`

Now what I COULD do is

`if(div[0]  && div[0].children[1]  && div[0].children[1].children[0]...`

but this would make my code blow up. I've tried to use the top voted answer in the linked question but this didn't work once I added the .children in there, it would simply throw false every time. Trying to access it via try/catch does work for the divs that do contain those entries.

Using `lodash`'s `get` works safely but I don't want to deploy 6kb of this module for something that might get achieved otherwise.

Comment: Can't you use a css selector and do a querySelector call to check?

Comment: Like `div>:nth-child(2)>:nth-child(1)>:nth-child(2)`?

Comment: Thank you, that might be a good solution but I haven't figured out how to access variables from my JS yet. Running on the SO site: `divOb = document.getElementsByClassName(' js-gps-track nav-links--link')[0]; document.querySelector("[data-name=" + divOb + "]");`

Comment: where possible you should use `<element>.querySelector` rather than `document.querySelector` (and use `.querySelectorAll` if multiple element matches is a possibility)