# how to verify if a property is null in a filter method

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of objects and I have to search them by id and name. Some of my objects have 'name': null and I get an error

> Cannot read property 'includes' of null

```
Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
      if (this.filters.searchBy && this.filters.searchBy.length) {
        result[key] = result[key].filter(r =>
          this.filters.searchBy.includes(r.id) ||
          r.name.includes(this.filters.searchBy));
      }
    });
```

I have tried

```
if (r.name !== null) {

}
```

but it is not a correct syntax

Comment: have you tried comparing with "!=", not "!==" ?

Comment: @Skywarth null object can be checked against with strict comparaison, `null === null` returns `true`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Comment: You should realize, that for arrow functions, you can write `x => { }`, where { } is a BlockStatement. Please review the different [arrow function syntax options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Also notice, that `function () { }` also works. This comment is in regards to your "not a correct syntax", and your comment of "can't have an if in a filter method".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional Chaining & Arrow Functions

You can use `?.` to avoid having to check `null`s on properties. Also, you can use arrow functions to easily filter an array in JavaScript.

Here is some example code:

```js
let list = [
  {name: 'John Smith', age: 13},
  {name: 'Peter Jones', age: 23},
  {name: 'Jane Doe', age: 54},
  {name: null, age : 12},
  {age: 72}
];

let result = list.filter(i => {
    return (
        i.name?.startsWith("J") &&
        i.age < 40
    )
});

console.log(result);
// Returns only "John Smith"
```

Without Optional Chaining

As Makyen pointed out, you may not be able to us optional chaining. In that case you can just check each field before using it, as shown below.

```js
let list = [
  {name: 'John Smith', age: 13},
  {name: 'Peter Jones', age: 23},
  {name: 'Jane Doe', age: 54},
  {name: null, age : 12},
  {age: 72}
];



let result = list.filter(i => {
    return (
        i.name && // If 'name' is null the condition will fail fast
        i.name.startsWith("J") &&
        i.age < 40
    )
});

console.log(result);
// Returns only "John Smith"
```

I found a function on a different question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23809123/8779719) which allows you to easily check nested objects. I've slightly modified it to check for nested fields.

```js
function get(obj, key){
  return key.split(".").every(function(x) {
        if(typeof obj != "object" || obj === null || ! x in obj || !obj[x])
            return false;
        obj = obj[x];
        return true;
    });
}

let list = [
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' 
    },
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: null, lastName: 'Jones' 
    },
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: {
      lastName: 'Jones' 
    },
    age: 46
  }
];

let result = list.filter(i => {
    return (
        get(i, "name.firstName") && 
        i.name.firstName.startsWith("J") &&
        i.age < 40
    )
});

console.log(result);
// Returns only "John Smith"
```

**Links:**

Optional chaining

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Arrow functions - a good article I wrote about arrow functions

https://dev.to/acroynon/javascript-arrow-functions-explained-3m04

Answer (score 1):

without the if, you simply write:

```
&& (r.name !== null)
```

in your expression and the compiler will accept it, or you can use the filter as follows:

```
.filter( (item) => {
  if (whatever_condition) {
    return item;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
      if (this.filters.searchBy && this.filters.searchBy.length) {
        result[key] = result[key].filter(r => r && 
          (r.id && this.filters.searchBy.includes(r.id)) ||
          (r.name && r.name.includes(this.filters.searchBy)));
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Have u tried this

```
if (r.name) {}
```